# How is the Auction House Fee calculated?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

When selling stuff in the Auction House there is always a toll, or a tax. Is there a percentage or a formula as to how much you will have to pay in order for the tellers to sell your stuff for you.

Comment: Please consider working to improve the titles for your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To post an item on the Auction House, the amount you need to pay depends on how long you want your item to appear for:

- 8 Hours = 6% of how much you could sell the item for to a vendor
- 24 Hours = 20%
- 48 Hours = 40%
- 72 Hours = 60%

But if you successfully manage to sell your item to someone, you will get the fee you paid back, but instead a 5% cut will be taken from you

If you are unable to sell the item, then you will not receive your posting fee back. The 5% fee will not be charged for you, however.

So, there are two fees:

- The "posting fee", that you pay when you post the item, and get back only if the auction is *successful*
- The "sold fee", which is paid only if you sell the item.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on a [guide to the LotRO economy](http://lotrovault.ign.com/View.php?view=Guides.Detail&id=10).

> Every time you post an auction, you have to pay a Posting Fee up front. The amount depends on the duration you picked (see the table below). The percentage is applied to either the Initial Price or the Buyout Price, if you entered one. In addition to this, the Auction House also takes a 5% Auctioning Fee for every sale completed.

Duration and Fees

- 8 Hours - 6 % of Item Worth
- 24 Hours - 20% of Item Worth
- 48 Hours - 40% of Item Worth
- 72 Hours - 60% of Item Worth

Comment: The meta says we should not use code ticks for quotes. Use quote marks instead!